# Embed YouTube Live in Wordpress website (auto update player)

Tags: wordpress, youtube, video-streaming, embed

I want to embed a YouTube player on a Wordpress site on which live streams will be broadcast. I manage the live shows with OBS, I would like to make the link always the same (or another way if possible to do it) so that I don't have to manually update the wordpress page for each live show. I want to start the live from OBS and automatically should start the live video stream on the Wordpress page. Is this possible?

I tried Google API by generating the API key for YoutTube embed V3 and restricting the key to my site, but it doesn't work.